# React Navigation: 'navigation.state.params' is always undefined in 'static navigationOptions'

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, react-redux, react-navigation

The heart of my problem is that when I have this in my navigationOptions:

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    console.log(navigation)
    console.log(navigation.state)
}
```

The first 'console.log' statement returns the navigation object complete with "navigation.state.params" containing the params that I have passed into it.

However, the second 'console.log' returns the 'navigation.state' object but for some reason the 'params' are undefined.

Here is how I am setting the navigation params (from redux):

```
function mapStateToProps(state, props) {
    let sum = 0
    for (let product in state.cart) {
        sum += state.cart[product]
    }
    return props.navigation.state = {params: {cartSum: sum}}
}
```

And my developer environment:

node         6.10.1
react-native 0.46.4
redux        3.7.1
react-redux  5.0.5
react-navigation 1.0.0-beta.11

Answer (score 6):

Used like this

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    const { params = {} } = navigation.state;
    console.log(params)**will show you the handlesave with object value hello**
};

this.props.navigation.setParams({ handleSave: "Heloo" });
```

May be this can help you , Thanks

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to go around this issue by implementing a method in the component class.

```
getNavigationParams() {
        return this.props.navigation.state.params || {};
    }
```

This will give you access to the parameters. But it does not work for nested objects.